# My Mocha test passes on first time but fails on subsequent runs when using watch

Tags: mocha.js, integration-testing, chai

I am writing integration tests using mocha and chai. I want to use mocha -w however whenever the code re-runs due to changes, the tests fails with the message that done was not called. However every time that I stop mocha and run again it runs fine. There seems to be some type of scoping issue, that when mocha re-runs some things are out of scope. Any help would be appreciated!

Using Mocha "mocha@3.2.0"

```
function sendGoodMsg(){
  return sendMsg(payloads.goodPayload, "good_msg")
}

function tooManyMsg(){
  return sendMsg(payloads.tooManyPayload, "too_many_msg")
}
function tooFewMsg(){
  return sendMsg(payloads.tooFewPayload, "too_few_msg")
}
function sendMsg(payload, type){
  //get process started
  let sentMsg = new queue.CCMessage( 'scheduler_service', queue.WORK, 'setSchedule' );
  sentMsg.context.origContext = uuid.v4();
  sentMsg.context.testType = type;
  sentMsg.payload = payload;
  return sentMsg.Send();
}

function receiveMsg(payloadType){
  return new Promise(resolve =>{
    const messageReceiver = new queue.MessageReceiver(queue.THIS_SERVICE, queue.WORK);
    messageReceiver.on('setSchedule', (msg)=>{
      if(msg.context.testType === payloadType){
        resolve(msg.payload);
        msg.ACK();
      } else {
        msg.NAK();
      }
    });
    messageReceiver.Listen();
  })
}

describe("should receive sent message", function(){
  it('should have the following fields', function () {
    return sendGoodMsg().then(()=>{
      return receiveMsg("good_msg").then(payload =>{
        return assert.isTrue(processMessage.messageIsValid(payload));
      })
    })
  })
  it('should not have extra fields', function () {
    return tooManyMsg().then(()=> {
      return receiveMsg("too_many_msg").then(payload => {
        return assert.isFalse(processMessage.messageIsValid(payload));
      })
    })
  })
  it('should not be missing fields', function () {
    return tooFewMsg().then(()=> {
      return receiveMsg("too_few_msg").then(payload => {
        return assert.isFalse(processMessage.messageIsValid(payload));
      })
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Have you tried calling done() in your final callbacks?

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic No. See https://mochajs.org/ "In Mocha v3.0.0 and newer, returning a Promise and calling done() will result in an exception, as this is generally a mistake"